# How to clear Smarty error or enable debugging

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, smarty

When I have a problem in Smarty I will get a dirty error message.

How can I enable debug mode or how can I get the clear error messages ?

This is a sample error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'list.tpl'' in
H:\Server\FrameWork\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127 
Stack trace: #0 H:\Server\FrameWork\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374):
Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('news/li...', NULL, NULL, NULL, true) #1 
H:\Server\news\list.php(157): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('news/li...') #2 
H:\Server\news\news.php(24): include('H:\Serve...') #3 H:\Server\sec.php(13): 
include('H:\Serve...') #4 {main} thrown in 
H:\Server\FrameWork\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a "backtrace" or "stack trace" - it shows you the exact point in the program that the error occurred, traced backwards to the outermost part of your code.

The most useful things to spot there are:

1. The first line is a quite reasonable error message: 'Unable to load template file 'list.tpl''
2. After the lines which mention internal parts of Smarty, you can see `H:\Server\news\list.php(157)`. So on line 157 of your file `H:\Server\news\list.php`, you are asking Smarty to render a template, and that's where the error originates.

So it looks like in this case, you have a line of PHP code asking Smarty to render a template that doesn't exist. It's hard to imagine what more information could be provided.